# How do you invert the colors on part of an element?

Tags: css

Imagine having a square `div` with styling:

```
div {
  background: red;
  height: 5rem;
  width: 5rem;
}
```

What other styles would you apply to it so that the bottom half of the red square has its colors inverted?

Answer (score 4):

You could use [invert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/invert)

```css
div {
  background: red;
  height: 5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  position: relative;
}

div > div {
  background: red;
  height: 2.5rem;
  width: 100%;
  filter: invert(1);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
  </div>
</div>
```